# Selecting coordinates of points below DEM (DTM)

Tags: python, dem, coordinates, elevation

I have a DEM file and a big list of X,Y,Z point (about 1M). Each of them can be below or above the DEM file.

Is there a quick way to select the x,y,z points below the DEM file using Python?

I did not find yet a solution on Google or StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to get the DEM elevation values of the same points xy coordinates (red lines projections in the figure below) using  [osgeo.GDAL](https://pypi.org/project/GDAL/) or [rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to read the DEM, [GeoPandas](http://geopandas.org/) for the points shapefile and [affine](https://github.com/sgillies/affine) to get the elevation value (see [Python affine transforms](https://www.perrygeo.com/python-affine-transforms.html)).

[image]

**With GDAL**

```
from osgeo import gdal
from affine import Affine
import geopandas as gpd
```

Open the dem

```
layer = gdal.Open('dem.tif')
gt =layer.GetGeoTransform()
T0 = Affine.from_gdal(*gt)
band = layer.GetRasterBand(1)
elev= band.ReadAsArray()
```

The shapefile

```
df = gpd.read_file("points.shp")
df
   ID    z                     geometry
0  18  140  POINT (204439.9038755086 89773.5004016017)
1  37  120  POINT (204404.5155014408 89844.2771497373)
2  25  280  POINT (204333.7387533052 89808.8887756695)
3  43  240  POINT (204262.9620051695 89879.6655238051)
4  60  110  POINT (204510.6806236442 89915.0538978729)
5  56  206  POINT (204227.5736311017 89773.5004016017)
```

The affine projection to get the DEM elevation values -> col, row = ~T0 * (x, y)

```
df['x'] = df.geometry.apply(lambda p: p.x)
df['y'] = df.geometry.apply(lambda p: p.y)
xy2rc = lambda x, y: [int(i) for i in [x, y] * ~T0]
def zdem(x,y):
   cc = xy2rc(x,y)
   return elev[cc[1],cc[0]]
df['elev'] = df.apply(lambda p: zdem(p.x,p.y), axis=1)
df
   ID    z                         geometry                 x             y            elev
0  18  140  POINT (204439.9038755086 89773.5004016017)  204439.903876  89773.500402  210.160004
1  37  120  POINT (204404.5155014408 89844.2771497373)  204404.515501  89844.277150  209.169998
2  25  280  POINT (204333.7387533052 89808.8887756695)  204333.738753  89808.888776  208.399994
3  43  240  POINT (204262.9620051695 89879.6655238051)  204262.962005  89879.665524  204.380005
4  60  110  POINT (204510.6806236442 89915.0538978729)  204510.680624  89915.053898  209.410004
5  56  206  POINT (204227.5736311017 89773.5004016017)  204227.573631  89773.500402  205.830002
```

Points above the DEM

```
df[df['z'] > df['elev']]
   ID    z                         geometry                 x             y            elev
2  25  280  POINT (204333.7387533052 89808.8887756695)  204333.738753  89808.888776  208.399994
3  43  240  POINT (204262.9620051695 89879.6655238051)  204262.962005  89879.665524  204.380005
5  56  206  POINT (204227.5736311017 89773.5004016017)  204227.573631  89773.500402  205.830002
```

Points below the DEM

```
df[df['z'] < df['elev']]
   ID    z                         geometry                 x             y            elev
0  18  140  POINT (204439.9038755086 89773.5004016017)  204439.903876  89773.500402  210.160004
1  37  120  POINT (204404.5155014408 89844.2771497373)  204404.515501  89844.277150  209.169998
4  60  110  POINT (204510.6806236442 89915.0538978729)  204510.680624  89915.053898  209.410004
```

**With rasterio**

You don't need the [affine](https://github.com/sgillies/affine) library (integrated in rasterio)

```
import rasterio as rio
from rasterio import Affine
# open the dem
with rio.open('dem.tif') as dataset:
    elev = dataset.read(1)
T0 = dataset.transform
# the shapefile
...... (same)
```